# $(K(a))^p = K^p(a^p) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

I have to show that $(K(a))^p = K^p(a^p) $ , where $K(a)/K$ is a field extension of characteristic $p \gt 0 $ .

I am stuck in thinking from where to start. Will be grateful if anyone help me in solving the problem. Thank You.

Comment: In characteristic $p$ : $(\sum_n c_n a^n)^p =\sum_n c_n^p (a^p)^n$, for the same reason $b \mapsto b^p$ is a field morphism $K \to K^p$

Comment: Very useful comment ! @reuns

Comment: But can't it be proved by showing that each is subset of other ? @reuns

Comment: That's what I did ${}{}{}$

Comment: Will you please give it as an answer ?

Comment: What is unclear to you ?

Comment: nah ! Its ok now !..